# Flutter http ios can not find all response headers

Tags: ios, flutter, http

I am doing a post request in flutter. Ussing http.post() This code works fine on android and gives me the response header with de cookie i need. When i run the same code on ios i do not get the cookie in the response

```
var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("https://myurl.com"),
        body: jsonEncode(body));
    print("The response header ${response.headers.toString()}");
```

I am ussing an InAppWebview widget.

How come de ios app response is different from the android?

I have no clue why this happens.
I have set sharedCookieEnabled to true on de InAppWebviewSettings this changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that cookies are handled gently, you might need to configure the InAppWebView to handle cookies properly. You can do this by setting up a cookie manager for the webview:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: WebViewPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewPageState createState() => _WebViewPageState();
}

class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController? _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("InAppWebView"),
      ),
      body: InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://myurl.com")),
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          _webViewController = controller;
          setupCookieManager(controller);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> setupCookieManager(InAppWebViewController controller) async {
    await controller.clearAllCookies();
    await controller.addJavaScriptHandler(handlerName: 'cookieHandler', callback: (args) async {
      var cookies = await controller.getAllCookies();
      return cookies.toString();
    });
    await controller.evaluateJavascript(source: '''
      window.cookieHandler = function() {
        return window.document.cookie;
      }
    ''');
  }
}
```

I'm using flutter_inappwebview instead of the default WebView.
I clear all cookies initially.

- Make sure to replace https://myurl.com with your actual URL.